# Calculate latitude/longitude between two other coordinates certain meters away

Tags: javascript, mapping

I am working on a Javascript function for calculating a coordinate with latitude and longitude on a "line" between two other coordinates. This coordinate that i need to calculate for example is 300 meters away from the first coordinate while the distance between the two coordinates is 1600 meters.

What i already have is the function for calculating the distance between the two coordinates that are known.

Gr.

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: This contains everything you need to know.... http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed my problem:

- First I calculate the real distance between the two coordinates in meter. (in my example 1600 meters)
- Next I calculate the difference of the real distance compared to the distance of the point I need to know. (in my example 300/1600*100=18.75%)
- Next I use sin cos tan to calculate the horizontal and vertical values of the latitude and longitude.
- After that I use the percentage to scale the latitude and longitude.
- At last I add the latitude and longitude to the coordinate.

This might not be that accurate but for me it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is on simple equation on line between to points on earth. You may try to find one, or use some brute force method.
You may use [Geolib library](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib) or try to write your own code on top of [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Then:

- You've got 2 points (a,b) and you want to find a point c in the path between them (also in a specified distance)
- Create polygon, use 4 points p1,p2,p3,p4 where p1 is a moved slightly north, p2 is a moved slightly south, p3 is b moved north, and p4 is b moved south.
- Having this polygon you may know if a given point is on the line between a and b, checking if a given point is inside of the polygon (you may use *geolib.isPointInside* function)
- Now you start from a and move slightly toward b (you know when you are on the right track) and calculate distance between generated point and a.
- When your reach distance you expected. You have your point.

As noted before this is an explanation of brute force method. It may be very complex to calculate, it depends on how precise you need to be.